# How to open a new page with specific dataset with a button click in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm a noob to React and I do have some react projects I'm working and learning. Now I have a code that I was able to successfully render the data from my Node+MSSQL backend. What my question is using a button click of one of the data among the dataset how to show that specific details on the next page.

**SingleShopOrder.js**
Route : http://localhost:3000/SingleShopOrder

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../App.css';

const SingleShopOrder = () => {

    const [shopOrder, setshopOrder] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNormacs();
      }, []);
    const fetchNormacs = () => {
        axios
          .get('http://localhost:8090/api/ctms/normacs/machine/NOR1')
          .then((res) => {
            // console.log(res);
            setshopOrder(res.data);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
      const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
    
      const handleChange = event => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
      }
    const begin = ()=> {
        console.log("Clicked")
    }

if(shopOrder) {
    return(
        
        <>
            <div className='mainCard'>
                    <div className="container column-left">
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Overview" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Overview
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/ShopOrder" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Shop Order
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Employee" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Employee
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Maintenance" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Maintenance
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='column-right'>
                        <h2 className='so_header'>Select shop order for Normac 1</h2>
                        <div className='wc'>
                        {shopOrder.map((so) => (
                        <div key={so.ID}>
                            <h3>S/O No :{so.ord_no}</h3>
                            <p>Item No :{so.item_no}</p>
                            <p>Item Desc :{so.item_desc_1}</p>
                            <button id="message" name="message" value={"1"} onClick={handleChange}>SELECT</button>
                        </div>
                        ))}
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </>


    )
}

return (
    <h1>Check the KepServer tags!!!</h1>
)

}

export default SingleShopOrder;
```

[Reference of "SingleShopOrder" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMTJn.png)

**VerifySingleShopOrder.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../App.css';

const VerifySingleShopOrder = ({ID,ord_no,item_no,item_desc_1}) => {
    
        const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);
        
        const handleChange = event => {
            setMessage(event.target.value);
        }
        const begin = ()=> {
            console.log("Clicked")
        }

    return(
        <>
            <div className='mainCard'>
                    <div className="container column-left">
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Overview" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Overview
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/ShopOrder" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Shop Order
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Employee" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Employee
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div className="item">
                            <Link className="navStyle" to="/Maintenance" onClick={() => begin()}>
                                Maintenance
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='column-right'>
                        <h2 className='so_header'>Verify shop order for Normac 1</h2>
                        <div className='wc'>
                            <h3>S/O No :{ord_no}</h3>
                            <p>Item No :{item_no}</p>
                            <p>Item Desc :{item_desc_1}</p>
                            <button id="message" name="message" value={"1"} onClick={handleChange}>LOGIN & VERIFY</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default VerifySingleShopOrder;
```

[Reference of "VerifySingleShopOrder" page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxiqf.png)

I tried to pass the props from "SingleShopOrder" to "VerifySingleShopOrder" page to get the data of whichever "Select" button clicked. What am I doing wrong here passing the props and how should I display the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rewrite it a bit:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../App.css";

const SingleShopOrder = () => {
  const [shopOrder, setshopOrder] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(0); // if message is not an array
    // then do not initialize the state as []
    // by the way the name of the var is confusing me
    // if it is supposed to store the selected order then 'message' is
    // inaccurate

  const fetchNormacs = () => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8090/api/ctms/normacs/machine/NOR1")
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res);
        setshopOrder(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  // here we are expecting order's id
  const handleChange = ({target:{value}}) => {
    // setMessage(value); // use this line if ID is a string
      setMessage(Number(value)) // use this line if ID is a number
  };
  const begin = () => {
    console.log("Clicked");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNormacs();
  }, []);
  
  if (shopOrder) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="mainCard">
          <div className="container column-left">
            <div className="item">
              <Link className="navStyle" to="/Overview" onClick={() => begin()}>
                Overview
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <Link
                className="navStyle"
                to="/ShopOrder"
                onClick={() => begin()}
              >
                Shop Order
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <Link className="navStyle" to="/Employee" onClick={() => begin()}>
                Employee
              </Link>
            </div>
            <div className="item">
              <Link
                className="navStyle"
                to="/Maintenance"
                onClick={() => begin()}
              >
                Maintenance
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="column-right">
            <h2 className="so_header">Select shop order for Normac 1</h2>
            <div className="wc">
              {shopOrder.map((so) => (
                <div key={so.ID}>
                  <h3>S/O No :{so.ord_no}</h3>
                  <p>Item No :{so.item_no}</p>
                  <p>Item Desc :{so.item_desc_1}</p>
                  <button
                    id="message"
                    name="message"
                    value={so.ID} // se the button value to current order's id
                    onClick={handleChange}
                  >
                    SELECT
                  </button>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  // check if message is different from the initial state
  if (message !== 0) return <VerifySingleShopOrder
      order={shopOrder.find(item => item.id === message)} // pass your props here
  /> 
  

  return <h1>Check the KepServer tags!!!</h1>;
};

export default SingleShopOrder;
```

Then in your VerifySingleShopOrder component:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import '../App.css';

// component now is expecting a prop called 'order' which have all the
// properties you need to display detailed message
const VerifySingleShopOrder = ({order:{ID,ord_no,item_no,item_desc_1}}) => {

    const [message, setMessage] = useState([]);

    const handleChange = event => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
    }
    const begin = ()=> {
        console.log("Clicked")
    }

    return(
        <>
            <div className='mainCard'>
                <div className="container column-left">
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link className="navStyle" to="/Overview" onClick={() => begin()}>
                            Overview
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link className="navStyle" to="/ShopOrder" onClick={() => begin()}>
                            Shop Order
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link className="navStyle" to="/Employee" onClick={() => begin()}>
                            Employee
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="item">
                        <Link className="navStyle" to="/Maintenance" onClick={() => begin()}>
                            Maintenance
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='column-right'>
                    <h2 className='so_header'>Verify shop order for Normac 1</h2>
                    <div className='wc'>
                        <h3>S/O No :{ord_no}</h3>
                        <p>Item No :{item_no}</p>
                        <p>Item Desc :{item_desc_1}</p>
                        <button id="message" name="message" value={"1"} onClick={handleChange}>LOGIN & VERIFY</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default VerifySingleShopOrder;
```

Of course, this code looks ugly a lot... but for a starter it's ok, you still have a lot to learn about react

I hope it's of some help

Comment: Hi Osmanys, thank you very much for the good starting code. I imported the "VerifySingleShopOrder" in the top and also added a cosole.log(Number(value)) inside the handleChange. Now I'm getting the ID value of the item I click in console. Should I add a <Link> somewhere to redirect after I click "Select" button to a new route with the gathered information? If I should then where do you think I should add the <Link> tag?

Comment: In the snippet I've posted whenever you click on a button the order detail is shown, there is an if branch for that. That's the simplest way without routes. Now, if you want to render the detail in another page then yes, you must use a link to navigate to that route, and then can replace the button by the link. I'm assuming you already have a routing handler like react-router-dom working. If not... then I'll show you how to start

Comment: Thank you again Osmanys :) I really appreciate your help. As you mentioned I need to learn a lot about react. I'm following tutorials these days.  Hopefully I could be like you one day!

Comment: @Glenn94 Happy to help. Keep coding!